# create pageObject pattern in javascript (protractor tool)

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using Protractor with pageObject concept to do e2e testing.

However, I have difficulties to understand why creating new objects is needed for each pageObject?

**Show you my question by code**

1. Currently, I define the pageObject in `pageObj.js` as

   `var PageObj = function () {
     this.method1 = function() { //whatever content };
   }
   module.exports = PageObj;`

and invoking it in test spec file as

```
var PageObj = require('./pageObject/pageObj.js');
var pageObj = new PageObj(); 

//use pageObj's method here;
pageObj.method1();
```

2. However, I think this way below is simpler, why shouldn't I use this?

Define the same method in `pageObj.js`
```

```
module.exports = {
    method1: function() {
        //whatever content;
    },
```

Invoke it as

```
var pageObj = require('./pageObject/pageObj.js');

//use pageObj's method here;
pageObj.method1();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you might have multiple tests using the same page object and you might want to store there data representing current or changing state of page during one test or suite of tests. Using it as a class/constructor function allows you to have a clear state between every test.

If your take works for you for now and the future and doesn't limit you it's completely fine, just for these more complex cases you might need to have to use instanced page objects to achieve what you need.

At our company we prefer to stick to one pattern to not have to adjust to use page object as an object here and as constructor function there. So to keep it more uniform across our tests we just follow the recommended style + this pattern has already settled and it's easier to switch between projects if they follow the same guidelines.

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks for telling this, it helps me a lot understanding this topic. I will mark it done.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tom mentions, using an object literal is fine, but can be limiting. I use them if I don't have to extend other pages (eg. a basePage). I also feel like instantiating page objects in the spec is a bit clunky, so I opt for a solution somewhere in between..

```
var PageObj = function() {
  this.method1 = function() { //whatever content };
};
module.exports = new PageObj();
```

And then your spec...

```
var pageObj = require('./pageObject/pageObja ');

//use pageObj's method here;
pageObj.method1();
```

Comment: Hi @Brine, thanks for sharing your great thought. I had the same thought as well, but when I see a test file with 5-10 lines of `pageObj1 = new PageObj1();` I tend to think if there is cleaner way to remove these boilerplate code. Can we put these lines into another `helper.js` file and only `require(./helper.js)` to hide all these boilerplates?

Comment: In my example above, the page object auto-instantiates, so you don't have to do anything in your code. No need for a helper, just require the page in your spec.

Comment: Thanks @Brine, it works perfectly! one typo from your answer, it shall be `var pageObj` instead of `var PageObj` :).